# Reject edit with custom rejected

Tags: bug

There is a pending edit to user Riemann's (not the mathematician) answer to [Evaluating Limit Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130442/evaluating-limit-question/130456#130456).  It adds content to the answer, which seems useful but should not be attributed to the original answerer unless the two are the same person.  I tried to reject it with a custom reason saying this.  The site said Buster, we need a better reason for this.

Comment: While it has nothing to do with the issue, it took me a minute to understand that Riemann is a user on the site and not the great 18th century mathematician (which may have solved this problem over lunch, or something like that)

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  I have edited the question to remove that confusion.  Perhaps this is unfortunate, as I was amused by your comment and this will spoil it for others.

Comment: I was trying to point an amusing observation... :-) Should I remove my comment?

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  No need.  As I implied, I was amused.  When I said "this" is unfortunate, I meant the edit, not the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that; this was a bug that would lead to any rejection with a costum reason begin rejected. Fixed now.

Also see [Sorry buster, we are going to need a valid reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129064/sorry-buster-we-are-going-to-need-a-valid-reason).